# Closing the app and reopening it in the activity I want, without doing it all over again

Tags: android

I can not understand a thing.
I am creating an android app that is connected to the DB.
When the user registers after login, once he is logged in, if he closes the application and reopens it, he makes it all over again.
I want that when the user reopens the app if he has not done the Logout he must be in the activity of the Login.

Can you advise me what to use?
The SharedPreference?

Apps like Facebook, Instagram and other things use?

PS. They are many users.

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: yes you can use shared prefs...

Comment: @SantanuSur Yup you are right. SharedPreferences is best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SharedPrederence` for session management of Login/Signup :

- When User login Hit API or Internal DataBase with validation  & get all user details & store it in `SharedPreferences`.
- Next time when User again open app first it will check the status of `sharedPreference` if login get Data otherwise Login screen will come.
- When User Logout Crear all Login Data.

**Initialization :**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Storing Data :**

```
editor.putBoolean("login_status", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("name", "string value"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("user_id", "int value"); // Storing integer
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

**Retrieving Data :**

```
pref.getString("name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("user_id", 0); // getting Integer
```

Reference : https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: Thank's for you answer Abhishek :)

Comment: Welcome @S.Bruziches,Happy to help you